# firebase get key values from list

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Doing a `subscribe` on /chat returns this:

```
[
  {
    "-L-bXjl628aN6MvCY7iA": {
      "content": "dsad",
      "img": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/neverl-fd59d.appspot.com/o/images%2F1512395563.jpg?alt=m...",
      "senderId": "TjRj5oSWrcdx8CiZyZhq625bJSx2",
      "senderName": "Khaled",
      "time": "December 5, 2017 6:38 PM"
    }
  }
]
```

The objects are returning correctly however, I cannot get the value `EwffbmmqgFc...`. (Highlighted in yellow)

How should I amend the code to be able to retrieve the path by listing the array content...?

### Code below:

```
 send(senderId:string,chatObject:any){  
   this.db.list(`users/${senderId}/chat/${this.authProvider.getUID()}`).push(chatObject);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the realtime DB every object gets a unique ID. Your chat node is comprised of objects. Inside your chat object(highlighted in yellow) you then add other objects (likely messages)  My best guess here is that you neglected to set any values/keys for your chat object likely because your simply pushing messages into the reference before setting values to the chat object itself. You should first create a chat object with name and whatever other values you choose. Once that is created you can then add your object to that specific chat reference. Hard to be sure without any code.

Comment: True, however, I am pushing to /userID and then adding chats from this specific user... So there will be multiple chats under one userId (highlighted in yellow).

Comment: Updated the question with code when pushing to list where senderId is the id highlighted in yellow.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with your chat object. I see your snippet pushes chatObject but the db screenshot shows an array of messages meaning your chatObject is only holding an array of messages and not any chat information

Comment: Yes, well I fixed it by returning an Object instead of an Array from firebase and doing a `Object.keys(snap.val())` which returns an array of keys (in my case what I need.) - Is this the right way?

Comment: Depends on the use case, if that is what you need vs a chat object (with info) that contains the array of messages that works too. Good luck !